# why rebuild all cpp files always in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I upgraded my vs2008 project to vs2013 and a new issue occurred.  My project is a c++ dll project and uses standard window libraries.  When I build the project, it rebuilds all cpp files even if I haven't made any changes.  My solution has many files so the build consumes much time.  I want to correct this error. Can someone help me correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A build that consistently re-builds all source files is typically caused by a missing file in the project.  For example, if a header file was deleted from a folder, but, not removed from the project.  The build will see that the file is missing and therefore determine that something has changed in the project so that it needs to be rebuilt.  For Visual Studio 2013, you can set the [“build output verbosity”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx) in the project settings to “diagnostic”.  Build the solution and you should see diagnostic information in the output window that points to the reason for building all files.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I checked build log and found out following sentence:  < Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB "Release\vc120.pdb" > and how to do for this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Configuration Properties->C/C++->Debug Information Format, select "Program Database (/Zi)". Once this is set, then VC should stop rebuilding all files.

Comment: This solves " < Forcing recompile of all source files due to missing PDB "Release\vc120.pdb" >". Thanks!